# What is the meaning of " got a funny look"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "he got a funny look" ?

What is the difference in meaning between two sentence,

> 1) he take a funny look
>
> 2) he get a funny look

Does "he got a funny look" mean "he made his face funny" ?

Deos "he take a funny look" mean "he see someone make the face funny" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither sentence is correct, the grammar is wrong.

Present tense

> I take, you take, he **takes**
>
> I get, you get, he **gets**

Past tense

> I took, you took, he took
>
> I got, you got, he got

So grammatically, assuming you intend present tense, it should be

> He takes a funny look
>
> He gets a funny look

Now, what verb to use with **funny look**? Take is never correct.

I can give someone a funny look; this means that I have a quizzical or disapproving expression. So **give** is the correct verb to describe the person making the facial expression.

If I am the person doing something odd, then someone can **give** me a funny look, or I can **get** funny looks, or I can **receive** funny looks. In all cases we are finding a verb to fit with **give**. Some examples.

> When I entered the room Jim gave me a funny look.
>
> I said "What's the matter Jim, don't you like my new hair-style"?

or

> I don't think my choice of clothes was appropriate, I got some funny looks from the hotel staff.